# How to increase java heapsize for ubuntu system?

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory, heap-size

Hello I am running a toolbox written in java from python. I am using Ubuntu. I launch the toolbox using jvm from my python file.

However when I increase my data size the program crashes with the following error message "java.lang.OutOfMemoryErrorPyRaisable: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

I went through some posts here on stack overflow for similar questions and I tried their suggestions such as going to command line and typing 
$ ***export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx4096m***
followed by
$ ***java -XshowSettings:vm***
However I get the following 
    ***Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 512.00M
    Ergonomics Machine Class: client
    Using VM: IBM J9 VM***
................(*there is a lot more here*)

Basically it doesnt seem to increase my heap size and the error persists. How do I increase my heapsize?

Thank You!

Comment: The variable to set is likely to be JVM dependant. You need to check how IBM's JVM does this rather than Oracle's.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx4096m`, try using `export IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx4096m`.

Comment: if you want to persist this setting, where should it be placed ?